# Integrate paytm in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, paytm

> How can i integrate paytm in **yii2** ?
>   Is there any module for ***paytm integration*** for **yii2** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a repository on github. Please check the given link

https://github.com/akhileshjha/yii2-paytm

Comment: hello,
i am integrating paytm using your files. after click on payment button page redirect to paytm page and showing given messges:
 Payment failed due to any of these reasons:

    Session expired due to inactivity
    Our system encountered an obstacle

how can i fix. please help me.

Comment: Did you confirmed your credentials with paytm and are you doing  transaction in test or production mode because they will provide you different credentials in each case.

Comment: A paytm team member sent some test details and said download files from https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_PHP link and add these into your code also configure according your details. This is very difficult to me because my project is in Yii2.
After that they said please make transactions with your code on  http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_api_doc?target=txn-status-api link. This is not possible for me because my previous integration doesn't work.

Comment: Then i found your link from stack overflow and  i download your files from git-hub and configure according to your steps. and i checked my credentials twice. but now when  i click on payment button it redirects my to paytm link and shows given message:

Payment failed due to any of these reasons
Session expired due to inactivity Our system encountered an obstacle.

i am really feel stuck in this. Can you please help me to resolve this thing.